# Html textbox that prevents user from entering negative numbers rounds up positive decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that prevents the user from entering negative weights in the Weight textbox.

```html
<input type="number" min="0" 
oninput="this.value = !!this.value && Math.abs(this.value)>= 0 ? Math.abs(this.value) : null">
```

Scenario 1 is working fine:
Input: 1.23 Output 1.23

Scenario 2:
Input: 0.05 Output 5 (I would like to get 0.05)

When I enter decimal numbers like 0.04 or 0.05, I am getting 4 or 5. I would like to get the decimal numbers as it is.

Comment: If you enter 5e-2 and you get 0.05 also on a number type

Comment: Should your input allow 0.00000045 or 45e-7 ?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss This is a textbox for weight, so yes it should allow 0.00000045. We do not let the users enter 5e-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a regular expression to strip all non-numberic digits.

- Not allow period(.) = `string.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')`
- Allow period(.) for decimals = `string.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')`

```html
<div class="box-tricks">
 <input type="number" min="0" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to allow decimal numbers in that textbox? (like 0.005)

Comment: Yes. use the `this.value.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')` instead of `this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')`. It will enable to put 1 dot for decimals

Comment: This is the most helpful answer here. I was able to achieve what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! Its better to create this solution as a function and put it on a `utils.js` file to reuse many times. Stay safe, stay awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off with using `onblur` instead of `oninput` as this will give the user the opportunity to complete his input before it gets "mutilated" by the event handler. I also changed the input type to "text" as this will require the decimal dot "." to be entered  - independently from any locale setting that might apply to your (or you users') browsers.

```html
<input type="text"
onblur="this.value = !!(+this.value) && Math.abs(+this.value)>= 0 ? Math.abs(+this.value).toFixed(2) : null;console.log(this.value)">
```

Comment: I tried different scenarios in your textbox. It is still allowing negative numbers and characters whereas in my textbox characters and negative numbers were not allowed. 

Input 1: abc
Input 2: -1.23

Although the output does not display any of those, I would like the user to not be able to able to enter negative numbers or any characters at all.